# Best practice for storing passwords for automation

Tags: c#, asp.net, security, passwords, password-protection

I know that the "how do I securely store a password?" questions have been asked many times here; and I know the answer is always "Never do this! Store hashes, never store passwords! Use bcrypt!"

But what about times when you cannot use a hash for authentication? For example: automated processes. Say I wrote an automation application that needs to log into an SFTP site or some sort of external service that requires a username/password. I can't use a hash to authenticate with an external service, so what am I supposed to do?

I tagged this question with `C#` and `ASP.NET` as these are the two areas that this question applies to specifically for my situation.

**Edit**: Due to discussion raised in the comments, let me clarify the threat I'm trying to address: I want to prevent an attacker from being able to read the plain-text password used to access the external service. Meaning that if they somehow gained non-admin access to our network or database, even with the database dump they would not be able to read the passwords in plain text.

Comment: Depends, do you need the password stored on a single machine or stored in a database so any machine in a cluster could use it? Also, you need a threat model, you need to be clear on who are you trying to prevent the password from being read. Is it someone who got a database dump of the database? Database dump + source but no way to execute code on the server? A attacker who can execute code in the same context as IIS? A attacker who has standard user rights? A attacker who has administrator rights on the machine? We can't tell you the best practice without knowing which situation you are in.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Thanks for your comment. I guess the best case would be storing it where any machine in a cluster can access it as the automated applications are spread across many different machines. As for the threat model questions, why would you not try to protect from all of the above? I wouldn't want the passwords compromised in any of those situations...

Comment: Because "A attacker who has administrator rights on the machine" is impossible to accomplish, they could just start up Wireshark, install a fake SSL certificate that spoofs the site you are logging in to, and watch the password be transmitted to the server and decrypt it and capture it that way. Or if it is not SSL or is somehow protected against that, they could inject a DLL that prints the password to a log file when it is sent to the API call that uses it.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Fair enough, you can't completely stop someone who has already gained admin privileges...So what about the other cases?

Comment: The reason you need a specific threat model is because each case takes time and money to secure. Most software projects don't have unlimited time and money to do proper penetration testing and hardening against "All attackers" unless you are working with extremely high value software that is a high threat target, like the software that manages bank transfers.

Comment: This kind of makes this question too broad to provide a good answer to - you need to better define the treats you're trying to mitigate at the very least

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I never asked what the silver bullet was for all threat models. I'm asking what the best practice is for when storing a hash is not an option.

Comment: @LewsTherin And what I am saying is the best practice for one type of threat is not the best practice for other types of threats. We can't give you a "General best practice" because there is no "general solution" to this problem. Solutions have to be tailored to a specific case for them to provide anything beside [security theater](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_theater). If you want a security theater solution that will make your boss happy without actually doing anything there are plenty of suggestions I could give you that are easy to implement.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I've added an edit to my question to address your questions. Does that narrow the threat model enough for you to answer the question now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are different options, both using encryption for password using a key, and protecting the key storage using HSM module.

**option (1): Using Database with HSM module**

You can store passwords encrypted in database and benefit from a feature in SQL 2016 "Always Encrypted (Database Engine)".
Always Encrypted allows clients to encrypt sensitive data inside client applications and never reveal the encryption keys to the Database Engine (SQL Database or SQL Server).

You can use  Hardware Security Modules (HSM) with Always Encrypted.

The  hardware security module (HSM) is a physical device that safeguards digital keys and performs cryptographic operations. These modules traditionally come in the form of a plug-in card or an external device that attaches directly to a computer or to the network.

When you get an HSM, you also get a software libraries implementing common APIs, such as Microsoft Crypto API and Cryptography API. These API are called Cryptographic Service Provider (CSP) and Cryptography API: Next Generation CNG providers.

Your applications can communicate with an HSM using those APIs.

For more securing the HSM module, you can:
- Tie the HSM to your Database Server.
- Tie the HSM to your admin login to Operating System Server.

for more details:

[Always Encrypted (Database Engine)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt163865.aspx)
[Using Hardware Security Modules with Always Encrypted](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlsecurity/2015/11/16/using-hardware-security-modules-with-always-encrypted/)

Also, Oracle database and other engine can provide encryption with HSM

[Securing Stored Data Using Transparent Data Encryption](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/network.111/b28530/asotrans.htm)

**Option (2): Store password in files in Protected storage using HSM module:**

- Encrypting files that contain passwords. This may be done by the operating system, an application, or a specialized utility such as password management software that is specifically designed to protect the confidentiality of passwords.
- Using OS access control features to restrict access to files that contain passwords. For example, a host could be configured to permit only administrators and certain processes running with administrator-level privileges to access a password file, thus preventing users and user-level processes from accessing passwords.
- As you are not using hashing, I exclude this option, but it's a mechanism for storing one-way cryptographic hashes for passwords instead of storing the passwords themselves.

Answer (score 1):

AES encryption and store the key in an external encryption key storage module, if you happen to have access to one of those.
Otherwise, you could try scattering parts of the encryption key on different servers or something but it shouldn't be the first choice.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, this shouldn't be solved with a HSM, as that also needs a password that you would need to save. Better is to always type in the password only when restarting the system (a server seldom restarts, so that's ok). The RAM is more or less safe (see [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/29019/are-passwords-stored-in-memory-safe)). See for discussion of small projects that have a maybe physical server that have a crontab [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/193047/methods-for-storing-plaintext-passwords-on-a-client?newreg=501d3b1ca33e4a19a518f28838f9cdd3).